# Severity: Notice Message: Trying to get property of non-object codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

**My Controller:**

```
function generateallmonthreport()
    {
        $month = $this->input->post('month');
        $year = $this->input->post('year');
        $familyid = $this->session->userdata('family_id');

        $fulldata['dates'] = $this->Itemreport_model->getreportallmonth($month,$year);
        $fulldata['members1'] = $this->Itemreport_model->getindependentmembers($familyid);
        $fulldata['members2'] = $this->Itemreport_model->getindependentmembers($familyid);
        $fulldata['members3'] = $this->Itemreport_model->getindependentmembers($familyid);
        $fulldata['members4'] = $this->Itemreport_model->getindependentmembers($familyid);
        $fulldata['members5'] = $this->Itemreport_model->getindependentmembers($familyid);
        $fulldata['year'] = $year;
        $fulldata['month'] = $month;

        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('itemreports/allmonthreportpage', $fulldata);
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }
```

**My Model:**

```
function getreportallmonth($month,$year)
{
    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT `item_date` FROM `items` WHERE MONTH(`item_date`)='$month' AND YEAR(`item_date`)='$year'";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    return $query->result();
}

function getindependentmembers($familyid)
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `familymember` WHERE `family_id`='$familyid' AND `dependency`='1'";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    return $query->result();
}

function getcountofexpensetype($memberid,$year,$month)
{
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `item_expensetype`) AS spancount FROM `items` WHERE `item_purchaseby`='$memberid' AND MONTH(`item_date`)='$month' AND YEAR(`item_date`)='$year' AND `item_expensetype` IS NOT NULL";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    return $query->result();
}

function getexpensetype($memberidforexpensetype,$year,$month)
{
    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT `item_expensetype` as expensetype FROM `items` WHERE `item_purchaseby`='$memberidforexpensetype' AND MONTH(`item_date`)='$month' AND YEAR(`item_date`)='$year' AND `item_expensetype` IS NOT NULL";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    return $query->result();
}

function getallitems($thisdate)
{
    $sql = "SELECT `item_name`,`item_price`,`item_purchasetype` FROM `items` WHERE `item_date`='$thisdate'";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    return $query->result();
}

function getexpensetypefinal($memberidforexpensetypeprice,$year,$month)
{
    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT `item_expensetype` as expensetype FROM `items` WHERE `item_purchaseby`='$memberidforexpensetypeprice' AND MONTH(`item_date`)='$month' AND YEAR(`item_date`)='$year' AND `item_expensetype` IS NOT NULL";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    return $query->result();
}
```

**My View:**

```
<table border="2" id="tab" style="width:100%" class="text-center m-auto table table-bordered table-hover">

                    <tr>
                        <td rowspan="2">Date</td>
                        <td rowspan="2">Items</td>

                        <!-- php code for getting all individual member header for individual expense types -->

                        <?php foreach ($members1 as $members1) { ?>
                                <?php
                                    $this->load->model('Itemreport_model');
                                    $memberid = $members1->member_id;
                                    $countforcolspan = $this->Itemreport_model->getcountofexpensetype($memberid,$year,$month);
                                ?>

                                <td colspan="<?php foreach ($countforcolspan as $countforcolspan) { echo $countforcolspan->spancount+1; } ?>">
                                    <?php echo $members1->membername."'s Individual Expenses"; ?>
                                </td>

                        <?php } ?>

                        <td rowspan="2">Total Expense On Common</td>

                        <!-- php code for getting all individual member header -->
                        <?php foreach ($members2 as $members2) { ?>
                            <td rowspan="2"><?php echo $members2->membername."'s Total Expense (Individual + Common)"; ?></td>
                        <?php } ?>

                        <td rowspan="2">Total Expense Of Family</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <?php
                            foreach ($members3 as $members3) {
                                $memberidforexpensetype = $members3->member_id;
                                $expensetype = $this->Itemreport_model->getexpensetype($memberidforexpensetype,$year,$month);
                                foreach ($expensetype as $expensetype) { ?>
                                    <td><?php echo $expensetype->expensetype; ?></td>
                                <?php } ?>
                                <td>Total</td>
                            <?php }
                        ?>
                    </tr>

                    <tbody id="tbodydata">

                        <?php foreach ($dates as $dates) { ?>
                            <tr>

                                <td><?php $thisdate = $dates->item_date; echo $thisdate; ?></td>

                                <td><?php
                                    $allitems = $this->Itemreport_model->getallitems($thisdate);
                                    foreach ($allitems as $allitems) {
                                        echo $allitems->item_name; ?> (<?php echo $allitems->item_price; ?>)
                                    <?php }
                                ?></td>

                                <?php foreach ($members4 as $members4) {
                                    $memberidforexpensetypeprice = $members4->member_id;
                                    $countforcolspan = $this->Itemreport_model->getexpensetypefinal($memberidforexpensetypeprice,$year,$month);
                                 } ?>
                            </tr>
                        <?php } ?>

                    </tbody>
```

The code seems to work fine but gives me the notice of Trying to get property of non-object

**Error:**

> A PHP Error was encountered
>   Severity: Notice
>   Message: Trying to get property of non-object
>   Filename: itemreports/allmonthreportpage.php Line Number: 68
>
> Backtrace:
>   File: D:\wampserver\www\home\application\views\itemreports\allmonthreportpage.php
>   Line: 68
>   Function: _error_handler
>
> File: D:\wampserver\www\home\application\controllers\Itemreport.php
>   Line: 91
>   Function: view
>
> File: D:\wampserver\www\home\index.php
>   Line: 315
>   Function: require_once

I cannot spot the impropper part of code.. Please Help..!!

Comment: Can you identify `allmonthreportpage.php` and line 68 within that file please

Comment: Yes, its the view file

Comment: And line 68????

Comment: `foreach ($allitems as $allitems)` And BANG there goes the contents of `$allitems` from an array to something else

Comment: And then BANG Again `foreach ($members4 as $members4) `

Comment: I am seeing a **trend here** `foreach ($dates as $dates)` BANG BANG

Comment: Yes its ___definitely trending___ `foreach ($expensetype as $expensetype)`

Comment: $memberidforexpensetypeprice = $members4->member_id;
the line below foreach ($members4 as $members4)  is the one where the error. is shown its line 68

Comment: i am new to programming. i couldnt get what u are saying..

Comment: A `foreach` processes an array so if you do `foreach($array as $array)` then you overwrite the array with the first iteration of the `foreach` so the basic syntax is normally to name array in the plural. So for example `foreach ($items as $item)` will give you many `$item` occurances one in each iteration of the foreach loop

Comment: All your `foreach()` loops have this same issue

Comment: Which means i am naming things wrong..
so is it like i should rename foreach ($allitems as $allitems) to foreach ($allitemsss as $allitems) and so on??

Comment: Well I would go for `foreach ($allitems as $allitem)`

Comment: Edited as per your explanation. Working fine. Thank you very much... I wasted nearly a day finding the solution. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated in the comments, you cannot use the variable that holds the array to also hold the values, like in `foreach ($members4 as $members4)`. It overwrites the value held in `$members4`, which makes the loop do things you don't expect.

To solve it, just use a different variable, like for example `$member` like here:

```
 <?php foreach ($members4 as $member) {
     $memberidforexpensetypeprice = $member->member_id;
     $countforcolspan = $this->Itemreport_model->getexpensetypefinal($memberidforexpensetypeprice,$year,$month);
 } ?>
```

Comment: Except as the other foreach's seem not to have caused an error. I would guess that `$member` is not actually an Object, just to make matters more confusing

Comment: Edited as per your explanation. Working fine. Thank you very much... I wasted nearly a day finding the solution. Appreciate your help.